# How to plot two bivariate histograms in a single frame?

Tags: r, 3d, histogram, overlap, density-plot

I am trying to plot two bivariate histograms in a single frame to see if they are equal. I have put an MWE below with randomly generated data.

```
x1 = seq(1, 5, length.out = 20)
x2 = seq(1, 5, length.out = 20)
x3 = matrix(rnorm(400), 20, 20)

y1 = seq(1, 5, length.out = 20)
y2 = seq(1, 5, length.out = 20)
y3 = matrix(rcauchy(400), 20, 20)

persp(x1, x2, x3, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue")
par(new = TRUE)
persp(y1, y2, y3, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "green")
```

The plot looks like

[image]

So, the plots overlap in such a way that I can not compare them. Can I make any one of the plots somehow transparent to do so? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `rgb()` with option `alpha` for `col`.

```
persp(x1, x2, x3, theta=30, phi=30, expand=0.5, col=rgb(0,0,1,alpha=0.3) )
par(new=TRUE)
persp(y1, y2, y3, theta=30, phi=30, expand=0.5, col=rgb(0,1,0,alpha=0.3) )
```

#### Result

[image]

**Note:** To avoid labels overlap, add `xlab="", ylab="", zlab=""` options e.g. to the second plot.